# What's setting LazyLoadingEnabled to false on my EF Context?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using EF5 database first.  On creation of my context, I'm setting `ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled` to `true`.  Something happens to change that to `false` (nowhere in our code is that setting changed).

At various points, I'm checking whether it's still `true` by using [this snippet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6C00C0B3-3BDE-4B1D-A992-3283C3F23D20) of code (getting context from an entity object).  The problem only manifests when running multiple threads (load some entities, then pass them through multi-threaded code).  It doesn't occur at any consistent point in the code, so it's impossible to determine what exactly causes it.

I guess I'm just hoping somebody might know more about the internal workings of EF and give me a clue...

Comment: How come you're not using `DbContextConfiguation.LazyLoadingEnabled`? Though, perhaps it's just a wrapper for `ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled` anyway.

Comment: I think that is just a wrapper.  This was upgraded from EF4, so the old way is probably just there for backward compatibility.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in EF 4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374758/lazyloadingenabled-being-to-set-to-false-mid-query-for-one-id-only

Comment: I restructured the code to stop using async methods and used only Task.Factory.StartNew and the problem went away...

Comment: @dudeNumber4 were you using EF6's async methods or other EF-unrelated async methods?

Comment: @bricelam : This was EF5

Answer (score 1):

An Entity Framework context is not thread safe. The problem you encounter occurs when multiple threads access a property that is lazy loaded. Internally EF switches off lazy loading when checking the value of a NavigationProperty and switches it back on afterwards. (See `RelatedEnd.DisableLazyLoading()`)

Thus what is happening in your case probably goes like this: One thread is currently accessing a NavigationProperty and before it finishes another thread tries to access a navigation property of an object attached to the same context. At that point in time lazy loading is switched off temporarily and thus no data is loaded.

EF explicitly states that the ObjectContext is not thread safe, so it is probably a good idea to make sure no concurrent access is happening from different threads.

Answer (score 0):

`LazyLoadingEnabled` determines whether related objects are loaded automatically when a navigation property is accessed.

I remember reading this in Julie Lermans Book: [programming EF by Julie Lerman](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022237.do)

You need a Dynamic proxy, for lazy loading.
You need a Public class with Virtual navigation properties.